# How can I find out which of 2 arrays has more elements?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I compare two arrays in PHP and find what which array of the two has more elements than the other?

For example, I have arrays

```
$a = array(2,3,4);
$b = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

How would I be able to dynamically return `the array $b` because it has more elements ??  is there a built in function in PHP that does that ?

Comment: count(array1) - count(array2) ?

Comment: You could also do array_diff($array1, $array2) then count that. And that would also say that array 2 is missing 1,5,6,7.

Comment: I tend to say the answer is obviously that you should search a little next to read the PHP manual: http://php.net/arrays ; http://php.net/count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question **"How would I be able to dynamically return..."** not "how would i show.." like other answers show...

```
$c=count($a)>count($b)? $a:$b;
```

If you wanted a function

```
function largestArray($a, $b){
    return count($a)>count($b)? $a:$b;
}

$c=largestArray($a, $b);
```

Comment: Thank you !! it was actually very simple ..

Comment: The `largestArray` function you wrote there is already included in the standard library and is called `max` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `return`, so I'm assuming this operation takes place in a function:

```
<?php
// Create our comparison function
function compareArrays($array_1, $array_2) {
  return count($array_1) > count($array_2) ? $array_1 : $array_2;
}

// Define the arrays we wish to compare
$a = array(2,3,4);
$b = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

// Call our function, returning the larger array.
$larger_array = compareArrays($a, $b);

// Print the array, so we can see if logic is correct.
print_r($larger_array); // Prints: array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment left by Steven, you could use the `count` function to determine array lengths. Then use the ternary operator to select which one is greater.

```
<?php

$b= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$a = array(2,3,4);

var_dump( (count($a) > count($b)) ? $a : $b );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '$a size is '.count ($a).'<br>';
echo '$b size is '.count ($b).'<br>';
```

OR

```
if (count($a)==count($b)) 
    echo '$a is same size as $b'; 
else
    echo count($a)>count($b) ? '$a is bigger then $b' : '$b is bigger then $a';
```